# communicate a .exe with a service c#

Tags: c#, service, exe, interprocess

I have a windows service that uses a `FileSystemWatcher` to see if there are pdf files moved to a folder, and then, when a user moves a pdf file into that folder, the service executes  `MyProcess`. The pdf filename is like this:   `name_doctorcode.pdf`.
code:

```
Private static void MyProcess(string pdfname)
{ 
  string sDoctorCode= getdoctorcode(pdfname); //brings doctor code from filename
  bool foundDoctorCode= FindDoctorCode(sDoctorCode); //searchs  into a data container (database, txt,etc..) to see if the doctor code is found
  if(foundDoctorCode==false)
  {
    // HELP to call exe file to prompt user to enter a correct doctorcode
    //pass the doctorcode to a variable
   string sNewDoctorCode = doctorCodeFromExe;
  }
}
```

Can you help me to do this?
Any guide,tutorial or code?
Thanks

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the [`Process` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: sorry, but I want to create a way to communicate an exe with my service , soI can get data from the exe and pass the data to the service. thanks

Comment: That's not really what services are for. The process that puts the file in the location should make sure that the file has a correct code. Having a service that requires input from the user (however indirect) is going down a dark road from which nothing good can come. Your service should log the error, or send an email, SMS message, or whatever, and then just keep on processing. The service should *never* block waiting for user input.

Comment: @JimMischel thanks for that advice, so you think that if I do as I wanted, with an exe that prompts user to correct the doctor code, the service will stop?

Comment: @EbaneoVk: The service will stop while it's waiting for the .exe to return, yes. Unless you code it not to. But then it might start multiple copies of the .exe. In general, what you're proposing isn't a really good idea.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. have a nice day @JimMischel.

Comment: also thanks for the data @Lex